# Check if a PostGIS topology with a given name exists

Tags: sql, postgis, topology

How can I test if a [PostGIS topology](http://postgis.net/docs/Topology.html) with a given name exists?
I don't want to run into error when creating the topology with:

```
SELECT topology.CreateTopology('topology_name', 1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT topology.CreateTopology('topology_name', 1)
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
  SELECT * FROM topology.topology WHERE name = 'topology_name' 
);
```

I'm assuming you have a custom `spatial_ref_sys` record with `SRID=1` or the creation statement would fail not finding that `SRID`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a conditional expression and `topology.GetTopologyID`, e.g.:

```
SELECT COALESE(topology.GetTopologyID('topology_name'), topology.CreateTopology('topology_name', 1)) AS topo_id;
```

Comment: This will still emit the error `ERROR:  Topology 'topology_name' does not exist`